# C# Exchange - Forward message As

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm using C# for an Exchange Online related utility. I authenticate to the server using an admin account, and that account performs some tasks on user's messages in specific folders.

If I want to send a message from a user (as opposed to the admin account in the From field) I can do this:

```
EmailMessage confirmationMessage = new EmailMessage(service);
confirmationMessage.ToRecipients.Add("recipient@contoso.com");
confirmationMessage.Subject = "Confirmation: " + message.Subject + " Sent";
confirmationMessage.From = "testuser@contoso.com";
confirmationMessage.Send();
```

And the message is sent with "testuser@contoso.com" in the From field instead of "admin@contoso.com" (the account used to authenticate to Exchange Online). This of course requires 'Send As' permissions, which have been granted.

However, if I want to forward a message out of a user's mailbox instead of sending a new message "admin@contoso.com" ends up in the From field:

```
foreach (EmailMessage message in itemResults)
{
//forward the message to each of the users assistants 
ResponseMessage forward = message.CreateForward();                    
forward.ToRecipients.Add("recipient@contoso.com");                        
forward.Send();
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to edit the ResponseMessage From property, and changing the From property of the message before converting it to a ResponseMessage doesn't make a difference. Is there way way to forward a message with a specified address in the From field?